# Android:Error while creating Menu

Tags: java, android

I am trying to creating a menu button to add items to a shopping list but I keep on hitting the following error:

```
 04-12 12:15:57.585    1995-1995/com.example.ShoppingList D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    04-12 12:15:57.585    1995-1995/com.example.ShoppingList W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting    with uncaught exception (group=0xb0d8cb20)
    04-12 12:15:57.585    1995-1995/com.example.ShoppingList E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ShoppingList, PID: 1995
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {com.example.ShoppingList/com.example.ShoppingList.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class menu
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class menu
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.example.ShoppingList.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.menu" on path:     DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.ShoppingList-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=    [/data/app-     lib/com.example.ShoppingList-2, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.example.ShoppingList.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It has to do the main menu class that somehow the compiler can't find. my main.xml file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_add"
          android:title="Add"
          android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

my code is like this:

```
package com.example.ShoppingList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    public static final int ADD_ITEM_REQUEST =1;

    private ListView shoppingList;
    private ArrayList<ItemParcel> itemParcels;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        shoppingList= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewAddItem);
        itemParcels= new ArrayList<ItemParcel>();

        ItemListAdaptor adaptor =  new ItemListAdaptor(this, itemParcels);

        shoppingList.setAdapter(adaptor);
        updateItemCount();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

and my project structure is like this:
[image]

Please have a look and let me know where the issue might be. I checked the http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html link but couldn't find anything suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to incorrect passing of argument to a variable in a function where the function couldn't find the list in a particular layout. Fixed it by using correct layout and correct id's on the layout and it started working